# BigQuery: Separate project for storing and project for querying

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a project in BigQuery to store data and another to query the data ? If yes, what rights should be given to the project querying the data to access the data stored by the other project ?
The idea would be to have a better control of costs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that!

You have to give the roles/bigquery.dataViewer role to the user that will be querying the data (at least). What that account will be depends on the use-case. If you are going to query from BigQuery UI you have to give such permissions to the mail account with which you will log in GCP UI, but you can also give such permissions to particular users or service-accounts for programatic access too.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-primitive-roles) you have the documentation referring to BQ permissions and how to grant them.

Comment: If you create both projects under the same account, it will by default be able to query both.